# A mathematical formula to count maximum number of possible numbers above a certain threshold.

Tags: number-theory

The problem is to find the maximum possible number of bars that can be obtained from a given set by incrementing them and checking if they are above a certain threshold.

For example,

```
Set A = {5, 6, 23, 34, 47} where A[i] are respective bar heights, and 
each a bar A[i] can be merged with another bar A[k] iff A[i] >= A[k] 
and by doing so A[i]'s length increases by 1 each time.
```

Now the problem is, given a particular threshold value $Z$, *say 35*, I have to find the maximum possible number of bars that can be obtained from $A$ having length $>= Z$.

In the above scenario, ans is, 1+1 = 2, because - $\{5, 6, 23, 34, 47\}$ can be reduced to $\{6, 23, 35, 47\}$ by merging $5$ into $34$ which increased the length of 34 by 1. Though I could have merged $34$ and $6$, or $34$ and $23$ to obtain the same result. Now the new set has only $2$ values having lengths $>= 35$.

I have solved this problem using programming by sorting the array and searching for lengths that are less than $Z$.

**Is it possible to obtain the solution mathematically rather than programmatically so that I can speed up my solution?**

Comment: Sounds like Subset Sum Problem to me.

Comment: @Cerkal It's absolutely not, in fact repeatedly merging the biggest element $e < Z$ with the smallest element is optimal and linear time. A merge here only increases the maximum of the two by $1$.

Comment: @Cerkal But here you are free to choose any number <= current selected number. For example, with 34, I could choose 5, 6, or 23, to increase 34 to 35. But no matter what I chose, 34 will be increased by only 1. Also, the number which I chose say 23, will be deleted from the set and should never be used to calculate the next value.

Comment: @orlp But again to obtain the next largest and next smallest, I need the sorting operation and then repeatedly searching for largest and smallest. Which is exactly what am I doing currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us describe the algorithm **GREED**:

> If there are at least two bars of length $<Z$, pick a bar of minimal length $a$ and a bar of maximal length (under $Z$) $b$, and merge $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$, and repeat. Otherwise terminate.

Let **OPTI** be an optimal algorithm.

**Claim.** For no input is **OPTI** better than **GREED**.

*Proof.* 
We may assume wlog. that **OPTI** never performs a merger $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$ where $b\ge Z$. Indeed, just skipping such mergers clearly cannot worsen the result; at most we are left with additional small bars to play with.
Thus we may assume that for any mergers $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$ performed by **OPTI**, we have $a\le b<Z$ (as is also the case for **GREED**).
Now the proof can be made by induction on the length $n$ of the input.

For $n\le 1$, no merges are possible, hence there can be no different output.

Assume $n>1$ and the claim is correct for all inputs of length$ <n$.
The following cases need to be considered:

- **OPTI** terminates. As any further steps by **GREED** never decrease the number of bars $\ge Z$, we are done.
- **GREED** terminates. Then **OPTI** terminates as well as it cannot perform any mergers (see the "wlog" above), and w are done.
- **GREED** merges $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$, whereas **OPTI** merges $(a',b')\mapsto b'+1$ with $a\le b<Z$ and $a'\le b'<Z$ and $(a,b)\ne (a',b')$ (in particular, there are at least three bars $<Z$). This case deserves further attention.

By induction hypothesis, we may assume that **OPTI** behaves like **GREED** after the $(a',b')\mapsto b'+1$ step.

- If $b'=b$ then $a<a'$ and the next step will be $(a,b+1)\mapsto b+2$. The same would have happened by first performing $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$ like **GREED** and then $(a',b+1)\mapsto b+2$.
- If $b'<b$ and $a<a'$, then the next step will be $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$. The same would have happened if we first did $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$ and then $(a',b')\mapsto b'+1$.
- If $b'<b$ and there are at only two bars of lengths $\le b'$ (so that in particular $a=a'$), then the next step after $(a',b')\mapsto b'+1$ will be $(b'+1,b)\mapsto b+1$. If we had played $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$, we end up in the same situation, but with an additional bar of length $b'$ at our disposal.
- If $b'<b$ and there are at least three bars of length $\le b'$ let $\bar a$ be the shortest bar after we do $(a',b')\mapsto b'+1$. Then $\bar a\le b'$ and the next step will be $(\bar a,b)\mapsto b+1$. The same could be achieved by first doing $(a,b)\mapsto b+1$ and then $(\bar a,b')\mapsto b'+1$.

In all cases, we see that **OPTI** does not outperform **GREED**. $\square$

---

If we assume the input is *sorted*, $A[1]\le A[2]\le\ldots\le A[n]$,  then we can compute the number of bars  that end up with length $\ge Z$ in a single pass:

**G1.** Set $j\leftarrow n$, $e\leftarrow 0$. *[$e$ denotes the number of small "eaten" bars, $j$ the indes of the bar we currently try to make $\ge Z$]*

**G2.** If $j\le e$, output $n-j$ and terminate.

**G3.** Set $d\leftarrow Z-A[j]$

**G4.** If $d>0$, set $e\leftarrow e+d$

**G5.** Set $j\leftarrow j-1$ and go back to step G2.

Comment: Is there a constant way to access the minimum element j >= Z before starting the merging loop in every pass ? Binary search could be used but is there any other way to access it in constant time?

Comment: Still taking long times for large inputs of Z in the order of 100000 and number of Zs being 100000. If I have to do these iterations for each Z, then in the worst case it would require 10^10 iterations, which is huge. Not sure what further optimization I could use to reduce iterations for subsequent Zs.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly merging the biggest element $e < Z$ with the smallest element is $O(n \log n)$ time and gives an optimal result. A fast implementation goes like this:

1. Sort the array.
2. Initialize two indices, $l, r$ to respectively the left and right side of the array.
3. While $l \leq r \wedge A[r] \geq Z$: increment the result and $r \leftarrow r - 1$.
4. If $l > r$ stop, otherwise $l \leftarrow l + 1$ and $A[r] \leftarrow A[r] + 1$ and go back to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because merging only increases the length by $1$, you don't care about the lengths of the bars you merge in.  Make one pass through your array, eliminating all numbers above your threshold because they are already big enough.  Take the largest number that isn't large enough and merge in as many smaller numbers as needed to get it to threshold.  Then take the next largest and so on.  When you run out of small numbers, you are done.

Comment: So, the best we can get is O(n log n) ?

Comment: @user3243499 It seems infeasible to be faster than sorting

Comment: I think it can be done in $O(n)$.  Make one pass to count the number of elements below the threshold.  Say you find $30$ with a target of $35$.  Now make another pass keeping the list of proposed items to be merged into.  If the first element is $3$, it cannot be the target of a merge.  If the next one is $10$, it could be, so keep it in you list of candidates.  If the next is $15$, that would replace the $10$ because they can't both be brought up to $35$.  Keep going, updating the list as you go.  That does it in two passes through the list, but the amount of processing is hard to figure,

Comment: It is similar to the fact that you can find the three largest of a list in $O(n)$ time.